# Core Data update if exists or create new managed object. Can I make this faster?

Tags: iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I have the following code, and I was wondering if theres any way to make this faster. Basically my app downloads some JSON (about 4000 records) from the net, and updates or creates my managed objects based on the data. At the moment it's quite slow, and I can see why, but I'm new to core data so I was wondering if there's anything I can do to make it faster?

```
 NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
 NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
 [request setEntity:entity];
 NSMutableArray *coreDataArray = [[managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:nil] mutableCopy];
 [request release];

 for (NSDictionary *dict in arr) {
  NSArray *filtered = [coreDataArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(code == %@)", [dict objectForKey:@"Code"]]];
  //NSLog(@"COREDATA ARRAY: %d FILTERED ARRAY: %d CODE: %@ COREDATA FIRST CODE: %@", [coreDataArray count], [filtered count], [dict objectForKey:@"Code"], [[coreDataArray objectAtIndex:0] code]);
  if ([filtered count] > 0) {
   Company *c = [filtered objectAtIndex:0];
   if ([dict objectForKey:@"Defunct"]) {
    NSLog(@"DELETED DEFUNCT COMPANY");
    [managedObjectContext deleteObject:c];
   } else {
    [c populateWithJSONDictionary:dict];
   }
  } else {
   Company *c = (Company *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Company" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
   [c populateWithJSONDictionary:dict];
  }

  float percent = (float)[arr indexOfObject:dict]/[arr count];
  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(updateProgressView:) withObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",percent]];
 }

 [coreDataArray release];
```

Many thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: are you sure that fetching the JSON data is not issue for slowing you app down if you are using SBJSON. Cause it is slower than others almost 9 times.  And also please accept some answers too.

Comment: hi, no the JSON parsing is very fast, I'm using JSON Framework. I'm pretty sure it's the filtered array inside the for loop that is slowing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should check out the [Core Data Programming Guide: Performance](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Performance.html) section

It has some specific advice for data import performance.

In case Apple moves the documentation again, here is a good search query on Google `site:developer.apple.com core data import performance`

Comment: thanks, reading through that helped. strange, I didn't notice that section when I read it before.

Comment: @chris Wanger link is dead, this is why ppl need more explanation in their answers not just a dead link. now this is useless accepted answer

Comment: Yeah, it's a tough balance between regurgitating Apple's framework docs and linking directly to them. I updated the answer.